# Recursive sub-generator call does not execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator

Python 3.6+ btw

From a nested dictionary, I want to print a parent-value if a child-value matches a string. To do this, I tried this recursive call

```
for child in traverse_dict(value, 'ready', 'y'):
    print(child)
```

That is, when the parent-key is found, I want to (recursively) check whether any of its child-values (and child-keys) match the respective string patterns, and if yes, print. (I would collect the values eventually)

Using the same call but outside the function works as intended (try last 2 lines of example code or see below).

```
for i in traverse_dict(ex, 'ready', 'y'):
    print(i)
# Output is 
# Y
```

But when I try

```
for i in traverse_dict(ex, 'id'):
    print(i)
# Output is
# checkpoint
# A
# checkpoint
# B
```

But I expect

```
# Output is
# checkpoint
# Y             <= (missing this, output of traverse_dict(ex, 'ready', 'y'))
# A
# checkpoint
# B
```

Any idea why it **FAILS** when called inside the function?

See this example

```
ex = [
    {
        'Id': 'A',
        'Status': { 'Ready': 'Y' }
    },
    {
        'Id': 'B',
        'Status': { 'Ready': 'N' }
    }
]

def traverse_dict(
    data,
    *args
):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            # FOR SUB-GENERATOR WHERE *ARGS IS PASSED 2 ARGS
            try:
                if key.lower() == args[0] and value.lower() == args[1]:
                    yield value
                else:
                    yield from traverse_dict(value, *args)
            except:
                if key.lower() == args[0]:
                    print('checkpoint')
                    for child in traverse_dict(value, 'ready', 'y'):
                        print(child)
                    yield value
                else:
                    yield from traverse_dict(value, *args)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            yield from traverse_dict(item, *args)


for i in traverse_dict(ex, 'id'):
    print(i)


for i in traverse_dict(ex, 'ready', 'y'):
    print(i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated with what I expect vs what it's doing - thanks for the helpful comments. Makes it clearer what my actual issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed wrong data in `for child in traverse_dict(value, 'ready', 'y'):...` line. In your case the `value` contains "A" because the `key.lower() == args[0]` statement is `True` when the key is `Id` and the value is `A` or `B`. You should pass the `'Status'` member of the current dict.

It means the correct line: `for child in traverse_dict(data['Status'], 'ready', 'y'):`

**Output with this line:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
checkpoint
Y
A
checkpoint
B
Y
```

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for your help.